# Fastest way to add multiple records to ADO recordset using C++

Tags: c++, asp-classic, oledb, ado

We have a data model that supports single table databases hosted on multiple servers. However we occasionally need to compile data from multiple tables for display on classic ASP pages. This is done in a COM object in C++. We gather the data from SQL Server using OleDb, with the OleDb logic writing the data straight into C++ structs. We then loop through the struct arrays adding the data to SafeArrays, then add these to the recordset. The logic to add the data to the recordset looks roughly like the following (initialisation and error handling logic omitted):

```
SAFEARRAY* fields; // Initialised to integer array 0 -> max fields
SAFEARRAY* values;
VARIANT* arraydata;

... //  initialisation logic

SafeArrayAccessData(values, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&arrayData));

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numDataValues1; ++i)
{
    // Add data
    arraydata[0].intVal = data[i].someValue;
    ... // etc.

    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < numDataValues2; ++j)
    {
        arraydata[21].intVal = data2[j].someValue;
        ... // etc.

        _recordset->raw_AddNew(fields, values);
        _recordset->Update();
    }
}
```

However it is relatively slow. It can take a second to add a 1000 rows of data, which is just too long in our environment. If I comment out the calls to raw_AddNew and Update the logic flies. So the issue is with how I am adding the data to the recordset. Any suggestions or advice hugely appreciated. Big thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's really slowing down, it might be doing a lot of disk writing. Can you populate the recordset in memory, then call the update function outside of the for loops to write the whole thing to disk in one shot? Or is the Update method even necessary?

Comment: Just tried without the update calls and everything still worked as anticipated. It was about 10 milliseconds faster too. However it still takes nearly a second to run, which is still just too slow.

Comment: You already have the calculated values in the array. The addnew call is probably doing a lot of song and dance before adding the data to the recordset data structure which is fed to the final consuming unit.  I wonder if you could create a data structure yourself which could be fed to the consuming unit.  Or cut out some of the middlemen calculation.

Comment: I had thought of this too - create our own data container optimised for this sort of thing. Thanks for your help by the way, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time since I've coded ADO database connections, but if I remember right you need to change your locking to adLockBatchOptimistic and then do a batch update. It is much faster that way.

[This might help you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678067(v=vs.85).aspx)

If I remember right, it still was pretty slow.

Comment: Cheers, I'll try this. Currently we open the recordset using _recordset->Open(vtMissing, vtMissing, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, -1); Just to note, there is no database connection, the recordset is constructed entirely in the C++ logic. ie. we are simply returning it to the ASP logic as a data container.

Comment: Tried this, the speed on the fastest iterations was about the same. I made no calls to Update/UpdateBatch at all. However with my previous logic every 3rd or 4th run would 'stall', taking nearly 2 seconds to run. Using batch mode eliminated this. Big thanks. Still need it faster though....???

Comment: Sorry, if I remember right there is not much you can do to speed it up. Unless someone has fixed something somewhere.